# How can I deploy a .EAR file package on wso2as-5.2.1 application server?

Tags: wso2, server, ear

I have installed wso2 application server on my lab server, the version used is wso2as-5.2.1.

I am experiencing that  I can't deploy a `.ear`, but only a `.war` file. Could someone help me about?

Comment: I suggest to try to make your questions looking beautiful, because goodlooking questions attract more and better answers.

Comment: Simply, from admin console I can not find the manu for deploy .ear file.In application--> add --> web application --> I  sow is possible to deploy only .war file.I dont found the menu where I can deploy  a  .ear file.

Comment: I think my question is very direct and simple question, I never liked support like this.So is better to spen money and use Licenced software

Comment: I am sorry, I really didn't want to hurt you by fixing your question and giving useful advices. I don't do this any more. I am so sorry. Good bye.

Comment: I want deploy an .EAR file extension on carbon cosole version wso2as-5.2.1.So when I navigate using left menu going on  application--> add --> web application here the cosole says me: " you can upload ONLY .war format file. But I need to deploy an .EAR file. What Can I do to deploy an EAR file on wso2 like i did in past on weblogic application server???

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Application Server is not a fully Java EE compliant Application Container and as of now it supports majority of the Java EE Web Profile specifications. Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Web_profile and https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS521/Java+EE+Support for more information. WSO2 App Server is not meant to become another Java EE compliant Server. Hence you cannot deploy Java Enterprise applications (EAR) files in WSO2 App Server. WSO2 Application Server has Web App deployment capability. Hence if you can implement your Java EE application as a Web Application (WAR) file and embed all the required Java EE framework Jar files in to the same Web Application, you will be able to run your Java EE application in the WSO2 App Server. More information on migrating from Java EE world to WSO2 is mentioned in http://wso2.com/whitepapers/evaluating-java-ee-application-migration-and-java-ee-service-migration-to-wso2-application-server/. Currently there is no other out of the box solution for this.